# Conditionally remove Storefront handheld menu for a single page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, storefront

I am attempting a relatively simple modification of code [provided by Woocommerce](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/remove-the-handheld-navigation-bar/) to remove the handheld navigation bar on a single page of my site with the slug `register`.

The code snippet provided is:

```
add_action( 'init', 'jk_remove_storefront_handheld_footer_bar' );

function jk_remove_storefront_handheld_footer_bar() {
  remove_action( 'storefront_footer', 'storefront_handheld_footer_bar', 999 );
}
```

I want to remove the menu only for a single page, so I tried to use the `is_page` hook.

```
add_action( 'init', 'remove_storefront_handheld_footer_bar' );
function remove_storefront_handheld_footer_bar() {
    if (is_page( $page = 'register' )){
            remove_action( 'storefront_footer', 'storefront_handheld_footer_bar', 999 );
        }
}
```

However, this does not remove the handheld menu. If I remove my `is_page` logic, then the menu disappears but that is not the functionality I need.

Comment: where is this code at? functions.php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use instead `storefront_footer` *(the same hook)* with a higher priority *(lower number)* than the priority used in `remove_action()` like:

```
add_action( 'storefront_footer', 'remove_storefront_handheld_footer_bar' );
function remove_storefront_handheld_footer_bar() {
    if ( is_page( 'register' ) ){
        remove_action( 'storefront_footer', 'storefront_handheld_footer_bar', 999 );
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works *(with any specific page ID, name or slug)*. You need to be sure that `"register"` is the slug of a real existing **"page"**.